# Connected compact set between a connected open set and a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be a connected open set and $K\subseteq\Omega$ a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It seems intuitive that there exists a connected compact set between $K$ and $\Omega$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the distance between $K$ and $\partial\Omega$ is positive, I can draw a closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega\backslash K$ such that $K$ is inside the path described by $\gamma$, and I take a compact (and connected, I think by the Jordan curve theorem) set $\hat{K}$ with $\partial\hat{K}=\gamma$.

How can I prove this formally in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Can't you simply take $$\hat{K}= \{ y \in \Omega : d(y,K) \le a /2\}$$ where $a= d (K, \Bbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega )$?

Comment: That will usually not be connected, but $\hat{K}$ as suggested by @Crostul is a very good step. That set is compact and has only finitely many connected components.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think the following is a good approach. Since $K$ is compact, there are $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in K$ with $K\subseteq\cup_{j=1}^mB(x_j,r)$ and $\overline{B(x_j,r)}\subseteq \Omega$. Let $L=\cup_{j=1}^m\overline{B(x_j,r)}$. Then $L$ is compact and $K\subseteq L\subseteq \Omega$. It is possible that $L$ is not connected, but we can join the balls with paths (because $\Omega$ is open and connected, therefore path-connected). Call this new set $\hat{K}$, which remains compact because paths are compact. $\hat{K}$ is connected and $K\subseteq \hat{K}\subseteq \Omega$.